# Extracting Validations using NLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, specifications

Considering  me a newbie into this but if I want to develop an engine to extract only validations from a technical documents like functional specification. Usually the validations are quick to identify.
If this can be done somehow I can use it for further automation.
I checked and few frameworks are available like

- https://opennlp.apache.org/
- http://nlp.stanford.edu/

I did few POC's as well , but designing an intelligent engine having generic rules is where I am getting blocked.

Any pointers will be helpful ...

Answer (score 0):

For extracting only validation you need to have the grammar or similar like structure maybe a regular expression. If you dont have ANY idea what type of validation you might face then you can follow un-supervised learning approach. Designing any generic rule is not as easy as it sound so you need to work extra hard for this.